# how to disable google cloud speech to text in nodejs

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm not able by any methods to stop the `streamingRecognize`. I tried to unpipe the stream, tried to unset client but I still get a 'Audio Timeout Error:'. Is there any method to stop recognizing?

Answer (score 2):

When we call [streamingRecognize()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/speech/2.2.x/v1.SpeechClient#streamingRecognize) what is returned to us is an input [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).  We then push data records through the stream for as long as we have input.  When we have sent all the data we wish to send, we must instruct the speech to text processor that there is no more data to process.  We do this by calling the [end()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback) method of the stream.

In your example fragment:

```
let recognizeStream = client
.streamingRecognize(request)
.on('error', console.error)
.on('data', data =>
    {
        console.log(data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript);
        recognizeStream.end();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to stop it without errors in case someone has the same problem this way:

```
let recognizeStream = client
.streamingRecognize(request)
.on('error', console.error)
.on('data', data =>
    {
        console.log(data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript);
        // first stop the microphone stream
        micInstance.stop();
        //call again to client.streamingRecognize with request set to null
        client.streamingRecognize(null);
    }
);
```

But now I get a Error Response: [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED at node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)